# PHP get value after '&' not taking?

Tags: php

In the following code....

```
<td height="27" align="right" valign="middle"><a href="General.php?category=Social & Political" target="_parent">Social & Political</a></td>
```

And in General.php page....

```
<input type='text' name='category' id='category' value='<?= $_GET['category']; ?>' maxlength="25"/>
```

Here the value taking only 'Social', instead of 'Social & Political'. If I change this to 'Social Political', its taking perfectly. Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

`&` has special meaning in both URIs and in HTML. In a query string, which is where you are putting it, it means "End of this key/value pair and start of the next one".

Run your string through [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) (immediately) before inserting it into a URL.

Run your string through [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) (immediately) before inserting it into HTML.

(urlencode shouldn't leave any HTML special characters in the string, but it is a good habit to push all data that is "not known to be HTML" through htmlspecialchars before concatenating it with HTML).

Answer (score 1):

Because `&` is a special character.

Use PHP function `urlencode()` and `urldecode()`

Answer (score 0):

use `urlencode` for the variables which you are passing in the query string

Answer (score 0):

To complement the previous answers, this will work

a href="General.php?category=Social %26 Political"

%26 is the url code for the character &